# Getting the return value of an exec process

Tags: posix, exec, return

I want the process running to exec. When the command exec runs finishes, I want the process that called  the process calling exec to recieve as a return value the value that the function called by exec returned. How is this possible?

I'm sorry. I understand the process is a bit confusing. 
So let me give an example I am in a bash script, call it b_scr.

In b_scr I     call a program foo. In turn foo calls exec which executes bar.
I wish b_scr to get as the return value of foo, the return value of bar.

So in b_scr:

```
# Call foo
foo
# print return value of foo.
echo $?

bar
# should be the same value as printed before.
echo $?
```

---

foo

...
   int main()
   {
   ...

```
 exec("bar",0);
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, your question still isn't very clear. You want foo to have the same exit code as bar? Does foo have to do anything after bar exits?

`exec()` is going to completely replace the running process, so if you call `exec()` without first calling `fork()` then foo will be replaced by bar, and so the exit code will be whatever bar returns.

If you want foo to call bar, and after bar exits, do something, you'll need to `fork()` and then `wait()`:

> ```
> int main() {
>   int status;
>   if (fork()) {
>     wait(&status);
>   } else {
>     exec("bar", 0);
>   }
>   // do whatever else here
>   return status;
> }
> ```